# Ошибка ValueError при запуске нейросети VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Всем доброго времени суток
Пробую запустить скрипт нейросети VGG16 для классификации изображений

```
"""
VGG-16 Implementation on Cats&Dogs Dataset
"""

import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import set_session
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, MaxPool2D
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.optimizers import adam_v2
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # dynamically grow the memory used on the GPU
config.log_device_placement = True  # to log device placement (on which device the operation ran)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)

# Get the data
trdata = ImageDataGenerator()
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="C:/Temp/Datasets/CatsDogs/train", target_size=(224, 224))
tsdata = ImageDataGenerator()
testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory='C:/Temp/Datasets/CatsDogs/validation', target_size=(224, 224))

# Generate the model
model = Sequential()
# Layer 1: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 2: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 3: MaxPooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Layer 4: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 5: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 6: MaxPooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Layer 7: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 8: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 9: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 10: MaxPooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Layer 11: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 12: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 13: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 14: MaxPooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Layer 15: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 16: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 17: Convolutional
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
# Layer 18: MaxPooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Layer 19: Flatten
model.add(Flatten())
# Layer 20: Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(units=4096, activation='relu'))
# Layer 21: Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(units=4096, activation='relu'))
# Layer 22: Softmax Layer
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

# Add Optimizer and check accuracy metrics
optimizer = keras.optimizers.adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Check model summary
print(model.summary())

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto')
hist = model.fit_generator(steps_per_epoch=100, generator=traindata, validation_data=testdata,
                           validation_steps=10, epochs=100,
                           callbacks=[checkpoint, earlystop])

plt.plot(hist.history["acc"])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title("model accuracy")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.legend(["Accuracy", "Validation Accuracy", "loss", "Validation Loss"])
plt.show(block=True)

# Try on test data
img = image.load_img("C:/Temp/Datasets/CatsDogs/validation/39.jpg", target_size=(224, 224))
img = np.asarray(img)
plt.imshow(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
saved_model = load_model("vgg16_1.h5")
output = saved_model.predict(img)
if output[0][0] > output[0][1]:
    print("cat")
else:
    print('dog')
```

В результате работы скрипта получаю ошибку ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0.
С чем это может быть связано и как ее исправить? Извините, если глупость спросил. Только начал изучать нейросети.
Версия tensorflow 2.7.0, версия keras 2.7.0.
Вот что выводится после окончания работы скрипта:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "D:/Code/Python/test/test10.py", line 94, in <module>
    callbacks=[checkpoint, earlystop])  
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2030, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)  
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-
 packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler 
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None  
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-
 packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 57, in __getitem__ length=len(self)))  
ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0
```

Comment: А структура каталогов какая? В указанных для трейна и валидации каталогах ещё подкаталоги соответствующие классам и там есть файлы с картинками? Такое впечатление, как будто не нашлось нужных каталогов или файлов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку. После того, как я создал папки Cats и Dogs в папках train и validation и разместил в них изображения все заработало

Comment: А, ну кстати по пути тестового файла в конце кода можно было увидеть, что подкаталогов и правда видимо нет, я правильно догадался :)